# What does this series of ->, arrow operators, in this php construct do?

Tags: php

I am familiar with object method access using constructs like `$s->doThis()`.  I am trying to decipher the following Best Buy 'Remix' php coding example.  Here it is:

```
$result = $remix->stores(array('area(11201,10)')) ->products(array('sku=8982988')) ->query();
```

Is this saying $remix->stores() returns an object that invokes it's product method that in turn invokes that object's query method?

I would like someone to clarify the syntax.  I'm confused.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Talk about obscure.  There must be a lot of things going on behind the scene.  Secret deposits of information awaiting processing by method further on down the chain.  I wonder why anyone would write such code.  Oh well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much yes – RiggsFolly 4 hours ago